# checkbox,get user selected value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 checkbox question,any idea how to get the user selected value using c#?

```
   <div class="form-group">
        <label for="checkboxes" id="checkbox123"  style="text-align:left;color:black">2) How much of the training can you recall?</label>
        <div>
            <label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkboxes-0">
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="checkboxes-03" value="1">
                All of it
            </label>
            <label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkboxes-4">
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="checkboxes-43" value="5">
                Not at all
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>

   <div class="form-group">
        <label for="checkboxes" id="checkbox456"  style="text-align:left;color:black">2) Are you ok?</label>
        <div>
            <label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkboxes-0">
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="checkboxes-03" value="1">
                Yes
            </label>
            <label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkboxes-4">
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="checkboxes-43" value="5">
                No
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

code above is my checkbox code.please guide me,thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I see no ASP.net controls in your code. All controlls are client side - so you have no access in codebehind. To access a element in your .cs file you need to set `runat="server"`

replace

```
<label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkboxes-0">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="checkboxes-03" value="1">
            All of it
</label>
```

with

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="cbAllofit" runat="server" Text="All of it" Checked="true" CssClass="checkbox-inline"/>
```

and access it in your **.cs**:

```
bool checked = cbAllofit.Checked;
```